# gem packetfu LoadError

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am attempting to use the packetfu gem.  I'm new at ruby on rails, so please bear with me. I'm using rvm with ruby-1.9.3-head [ x86_64 ].  I also have Mac OSX 10.7.4 I am getting this error when trying to run sudo ruby app/models/simpleSniff.rb

```
/Users/aragorn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- packetfu (LoadError)
from /Users/aragorn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from app/simpleSniff.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

The code contained in simpleSniff.rb is

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'packetfu'

include PacketFu
iface = "eth1"

cap = Capture.new(:iface => iface, :start => true)
cap.stream.each do |p|
 put p
end
```

$gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.4)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
packetfu (1.1.5)
pcaprub (0.11.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rspec (2.11.0, 0.9.4)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.2)
rspec-mocks (2.11.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.6)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sass (3.2.1)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sdoc (0.3.16)
sprockets (2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.7)
```

Then finally my Gemfile is

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem "rails", "3.2.8"
gem "rspec", "~> 0.9.2"
gem "sdoc", "~> 0.3.16"
gem "pcaprub", "~> 0.11.2"
gem "packetfu", "~>1.1.5"
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: What happens when you run it without sudo?  Did you install RVM as a single-user installation?  I'm guessing it's something to do with RVM being weird under sudo.

Answer (score 0):

A) The require problem specifically is because you're sudo'ing and not rvmsudo'ing (which will keep your ruby environment in tact)

B) If PacketFu and Pcaprub and injection and capture all works on your OS X machine, please let me know! I would be both shocked and awed. I've heard rumor it works.. for some people. I've never actually seen it with my own eyeballs, though.